# Commutator subgroup of dihedral group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, dihedral-groups

[image]

This problem is from w.Hungerford.

### My solution:

Note that $a^{-1} =a^{n-1}$ and $b^{-1}= b$.

a)  $a^{2} = a a = a b b^{-1} a = a b b a = a b a^{n-1} b =a b a^{-1} b^{-1}$

So, $a^2$ is in commutator of $D_n$

Now,$D'_n= \langle a^2 \rangle$

c) for even case:
n= 2m , where m is any natural number 
And then $a^{2m} = e $   so $ |a^2|=m$

And then $D'_n$ isomorphic to $Z_m$

But what about the odd case?

I try to prove that $|a^2|= n$, 
but I couldn't come up with a solution

Comment: You are fine with $a^2\in D'_n$. But your claim that $D'_n$ is generated by $a^2$ is not justified by what you've written. You know $\langle a^2\rangle\subseteq D'_n$, but you have not shown they are equal. You would need to show they are equal. By the way, if $n$ is odd, then $\langle a^2\rangle = \langle a\rangle$.