# Are the groups $\mathbb{A}_5$ and $\mathbb{S}_3 \times \mathbb{D}_5$ isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Are the groups $\mathbb{A}_5$ and $\mathbb{S}_3 \times \mathbb{D}_5$ isomorphic?

Is it okay to say something like this: The group $\mathbb{A}_5$ is generated from $3$-cycles and double transpositions, so its elements have order $1$, $2$ or $3$. $|\mathbb{S}_3| = 3! = 6$, so its elements have order $1$, $2$, $3$ or $6$ (order of an element of a finite group divides the order of group). Similarly, because $|\mathbb{D}_5| = 2 \cdot 5 = 10$, its elements have order $1$, $2$ or $5$. So for example, in $\mathbb{S}_3 \times \mathbb{D}_5$ we have an element of order $5$, but in $\mathbb{A}_5$ an element of order $5$ does not exist, so they are not isomorphic.

Also, I had problems finding $Z(\mathbb{S}_3 \times \mathbb{D}_5)$, what to do with that?

Comment: Seems correct to me

Comment: There **do exist** element of order $5$ in $\Bbb{A}_5$ (the signature of $(1 2 3 4 5)$ is $(-1)^4=1$ thus it belongs to $\Bbb{A}_5$). You can instead use the fact that the former is a simple group and the latter is obviously not.

Comment: @Zerox I am not familiar with the term simple group, is there any possibility to do this using only knowledge about orders?

Comment: What are orders of elements in $\mathbb{A_5}$?

Comment: You can count the elements of order $5$. The group $A_5$ has $24$ elements of order $5$ (all the $5$-cycles) while $S_3 \times D_5$ has only $4$ elements of order $5$ (all contained in the second factor).

Comment: $S_3\times D_5$ has elements of orders $6$, $10$ and $15$. The group $A_5$ has none of those.

Comment: Group $S_3\times D_5$ has an element of order $15$, but $A_5$ does not.

Comment: @kabenyuk I am a little confused about how I generally find what element-order is possible in $\mathbb{A}_n$?

Comment: @Martino what about center of group? $Z(S_3 \times D_5)$

Comment: @smth The order of a permutation is equal to  the least common multiple of its independent cycle lengths

Comment: $Z(S_3 \times D_5) = Z(S_3) \times Z(D_5) = \{1\} \times \{1\} = \{(1,1)\}$. The center of $A_5$ is trivial too, so this idea does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cycle structures of the elements of $A_5$ are $1$, $(**)(**)$, $(***)$, $(*****)$, so the orders of the elements of $A_5$ are $1$, $2$, $3$ and $5$. The cycle structures $(**)$, $(****)$, $(**)(***)$ do not appear because they correspond to odd elements (permutations with sign equal to $-1$). It is easy to count the $5$-cycles: they are of the form $(1****)$ so there are precisely $4!=24$ elements of order $5$ in $A_5$.

On the other hand, the elements of $S_3 \times D_5$ of order $5$ are of the form $(1,x)$ where $x \in D_5$ has order $5$. The group $D_5$ has a unique normal subgroup of index $2$ and order $5$, so it contains precisely $4$ elements of order $5$. Therefore $S_3 \times D_5$ has precisely $4$ elements of order $5$. Since this number is not equal to the number of elements of $A_5$ of order $5$, we deduce that $A_5$ and $S_3 \times D_5$ are not isomorphic.

Another possibility, pointed out by Jirky Lahtonen and kabenyuk in the comments, is to observe that if $a \in S_3$ has order $3$ and $b \in D_5$ has order $5$ then $(a,b) \in S_3 \times D_5$ has order $15$ and $A_5$ has no elements of order $15$, so $A_5$ and $S_3 \times D_5$ are not isomorphic.

Answer (score 0):

It is well known that $A_5$ is a perfect group, i.e., satisfies $[A_5,A_5]=A_5$, but $S_3\cong D_3$ and $D_5$ are not, hence $S_3\times D_5$ is not perfect. So the groups cannot be isomorphic.

References:

[How can I prove that $A_5$ is perfect?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/781311/how-can-i-prove-that-a-5-is-perfect)

[Commutator subgroup of dihedral group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3410613/commutator-subgroup-of-dihedral-group)

Answer (score -2):

$A_5$ is simple.   But $S_3×D_5$ has normal subgroups $S_3,D_5$, so that they can't be isomorphic.

Comment: I think it is much more difficult to prove that $A_5$ is simple than to show that its commutator subalgebra equals $A_5$. Of course, if one can use that $A_5$ is simple, then this is a good solution.